# CIVICRMSEPA Error sepasettings.tpl not found after new installation

Tags: extension, error-page, civisepa

I have reinstalled Civicrm and the extension Civicrmsepa.
When calling the Civicrm settings I get an error message that the sepasettings.tpl is not found.

Now I can't do chmod on the data & uoload files in www-data at my web host. I think this is the problem.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this.

[image]
Many thanks and
best regards

Answer (score 2):

Its a known issue for Smarty3, I have pushed a PR for the https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/pull/701

You can apply the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/Project60/org.project60.sepa/pull/701.patch) or comment CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH line in your civicrm.settings.php

```
cd org.project60.sepa
curl -0 https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/Project60/org.project60.sepa/pull/701.patch > 701.patch
patch < 701.patch
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, I have copied the patch in a file and placed it under "civi/web/core/tools/scripts".
I just don't know how to execute it.                                                                                                                               
"patch -R < filewithyoutext"  ?? 
Greetings Günter

Comment: I have added commands to patch

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to apply the patch, but I get a
error message.
Could you help me again?
Even if I'm not the fittest person on the console.

Greetings Günter

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You have posted this as an answer, but it looks like another question. This would be better posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hello,

I can't comment on the post because I get the message "You must have 50 reputation to comment".
Do you have a tip on how to do it?

Greetings

Comment: Since you can't put images in a comment, probably best to edit your original question and add the screenshot there.